# WP Contact Form 7 email with shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have CF7 installed on my WP.
The problem is - I receive emails with CF7 shortcodes in subject and content. The shortcodes aren't displayin the real values. What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are putting in the form and message body?

Comment: Based on your description, you're using the wrong tags. Pay attention to what you need to add in your form template, and what do you need to add in your mail template, they're different. For example: in your form template you need to add `[text* first-name]` , but in your mail template you need to use  `[first-name]`. Also, make sure the tags EXIST

Comment: So here's what I've got: http://postimg.org/image/va2cdgt99/ and the resulting emails looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/mscsd3497/

Comment: Screen shot the email part too (in editing screen)

Comment: Me too facing the same problem.If anybody solved it.please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is happening because you have the name of the inputs as "Name", "Email", "Betreff", and "IhrAnliegen", however, when you are sending the email it is looking for input names of "your-name", "your-email", "your-subject", and "your-message". Change what you have to:

```
Von: [Name] <[Email]>
Betreff: [Betreff]

Nachrichtentext:
[IhrAnliegen]
```

Should show the correct information when sending/receiving an email from the contact form.